# Large Dataframe Column multiplication

Tags: python, pandas, memory, vectorization

I have a very large dataframe

```
in>> all_data.shape
out>> (228714, 436)
```

What I would like to do effciently is multiply many of the columns together.  I started with a for loop and list of columns--the most effcient way I have found is

```
from itertools import combinations
newcolnames=list(all_data.columns.values) 
newcolnames=newcolnames[0:87]
#make cross products (the columns I want to operate on are the first 87)
for c1, c2 in combinations(newcolnames, 2):
    all_data['{0}*{1}'.format(c1,c2)] = all_data[c1] * all_data[c2]
```

The problem as one may guess is I have 87 columns which would give on the order of 3800 new columns (yes this is what I intended).  Both my jupyter notebook and ipython shell choke on this calculation.  I need to figure a better way to undertake this multiplication.

Is there a more efficient way to vectorize and/or process?  Perhaps using a numpy array (my dataframe has been processed and now contains only numbers and NANs, it started with categorical variables).

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned NumPy in the question, that might be a viable option here, specially because you might want to work in 2D space of NumPy instead of 1D columnar processing with pandas. To start off, you can convert the dataframe to a NumPy array with a call to `np.array`, like so -

```
arr = np.array(df) # df is the input dataframe
```

Now, you can get the pairwise combinations of the column IDs and then index into the columns and perform column-wise multiplications and all of this would be done in a vectorized manner, like so -

```
idx = np.array(list(combinations(newcolnames, 2)))
out = arr[:,idx[:,0]]*arr[:,idx[:,1]]
```

Sample run -

```
In [117]: arr = np.random.randint(0,9,(4,8))
     ...: newcolnames = [1,4,5,7]
     ...: for c1, c2 in combinations(newcolnames, 2):
     ...:     print arr[:,c1] * arr[:,c2]
     ...:     
[16  2  4 56]
[64  2  6 16]
[56  3  0 24]
[16  4 24 14]
[14  6  0 21]
[56  6  0  6]

In [118]: idx = np.array(list(combinations(newcolnames, 2)))
     ...: out = arr[:,idx[:,0]]*arr[:,idx[:,1]]
     ...: 

In [119]: out.T
Out[119]: 
array([[16,  2,  4, 56],
       [64,  2,  6, 16],
       [56,  3,  0, 24],
       [16,  4, 24, 14],
       [14,  6,  0, 21],
       [56,  6,  0,  6]])
```

Finally, you can create the output dataframe with propers column headers (if needed), like so -

```
>>> headers = ['{0}*{1}'.format(idx[i,0],idx[i,1]) for i in range(len(idx))]
>>> out_df = pd.DataFrame(out,columns = headers)
>>> df
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0  6  1  1  6  1  5  6  3
1  6  1  2  6  4  3  8  8
2  5  1  4  1  0  6  5  3
3  7  2  0  3  7  0  5  7
>>> out_df
   1*4  1*5  1*7  4*5  4*7  5*7
0    1    5    3    5    3   15
1    4    3    8   12   32   24
2    0    6    3    0    0   18
3   14    0   14    0   49    0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the `df.eval()` method:

```
for c1, c2 in combinations(newcolnames, 2):
    all_data['{0}*{1}'.format(c1,c2)] = all_data.eval('{} * {}'.format(c1, c2))
```

Comment: That didn't seem to change much--it will still taking multiple hours and all my system memory (8GB). It is very odd in that if i break the process into chunks (like say do the first 5 columns).  As I go on, the process slows down, despite needing to do fewer calculations.  The first "round" for column 1 should do 86 column calculations, while around 40 I should be down to 40 columns.  In fact, the first part ran in seconds, while it took over an hour to do columns 40-45.  Just weird.

Comment: I am afraid a dataframe of 228714 rows and 3800+ columns will use up your 8GB memory, suppose 16 bits double in your df, 228714*3800*16/1024**3 = 12.95 GB